# WPF NET. 3.5 C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How do I resolve it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, runtime-error

I have a project programmed in C # NET 3.5 in WPF which start very well in debug.
Having a low level with everything that affects the "WPF" I wish I could still succeed in this project to tell me that I succeeded.
I can not send you my `RootWindow.xaml.cs` completely because it has more than 9000 lines and it can be complicated.

Anyway, my problem occurs when I click on a button in my project, **Visual Studio** sends me back to the line that tells me `null` but I do not know how to remedy this very frequent error according to my research.

Here is the error in question:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in EWIN_THEME_MAKER.exe.
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

So, when I click on the button, the object that is called `null` is highlighted by VS, so this is:

```
 public void StartPreview_Theme()
    {
        this.setTheme();
        this.previewMaker.MakePreview(ref this.theme);
    }
```

> this.previewMaker = null

Yet I refer my class well at the very beginning of my class `RootWindow.xaml.cs`

```
    private PreviewMaker previewMaker;
```

So I searched in my `PreviewMaker` class but I do not see what might be`null`. Especially since it seems complicated because several classes are referenced in the end. There are: `PreviewMaker`, `Theme`, `LayoutManager`

In my `PreviewMaker` this code corresponds to the action that happens when I click the button:

```
 public void MakePreview(ref Theme theme)
    {
        this.layoutManager.rootWindow = this.rootWindow;
        this.layoutManager.setThemeInfo(theme);
        if (this.layoutManager.changeLayout())
        {
            this.ConvertLayout(ref theme);
            this.ReloadPreviewImage();
            theme.IsFirstConvert = false;
            theme.setChangeFix();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this.rootWindow, Resources.Dialog_Err_Convert, Resources.Dialog_Err_Header);
        }
    }
```

I also point out that there is an error in this line, which says `null`:

```
MessageBox.Show(this.rootWindow, Resources.Dialog_Err_Convert, Resources.Dialog_Err_Header);
```

Where could this problem come from?

I do not send my classes because they are too long, nevertheless if it is necessary I can put it if it can help me and help others.

`PreviewMaker.cs:`

```
    using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using EWIN_THEME_MAKER.Properties;
using EWIN_THEME_MAKER.ThemeMaker.Views;

namespace EWIN_THEME_MAKER.ThemeMaker
{
    public class PreviewMaker
    {
        private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
        private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
        private LayoutManager layoutManager = new LayoutManager();
        private const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
        private const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 2;
        private const int WM_QUIT = 18;
        private const int WM_COPYDATA = 74;
        private string convertPath;
        private string lytviewerPath;
        private string layoutFolderPath;
        private string layoutDName;
        private string layoutDPlayName;
        private string layoutUName;
        private string layoutUPlayName;
        private string outputDFolderPath;
        private string outputDPlayFolderPath;
        private string outputUFolderPath;
        private string outputUPlayFolderPath;
        public RootWindow rootWindow;
        private IntPtr hWnd;

        public PreviewMaker()
        {
            this.convertPath =  ThemeBinaryConverter.App.tmakeRootPath + "tools\\LayoutConverter\\NW4C_LayoutConverter.exe";
            this.lytviewerPath =  ThemeBinaryConverter.App.tmakeRootPath + "tools\\lytviewer\\lytviewer.exe";
            this.layoutFolderPath =  ThemeBinaryConverter.App.tmakeRootPath + "resources\\clyt\\Menu\\layout_out\\";
            this.layoutDName = this.layoutFolderPath + "DummyMenu_D_00";
            this.layoutDPlayName = this.layoutFolderPath + "DummyMenu_D_00_play";
            this.layoutUName = this.layoutFolderPath + "DummyMenu_U_00";
            this.layoutUPlayName = this.layoutFolderPath + "DummyMenu_U_00_play";
            string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
            this.outputDFolderPath = tempPath + "menu_d";
            this.outputDPlayFolderPath = tempPath + "menu_anim_d";
            this.outputUFolderPath = tempPath + "menu_u";
            this.outputUPlayFolderPath = tempPath + "menu_anim_u";
        }

        private void ExecConvertLayout(string inputCLYTFilePath, string inputCLANFilePath, string outputFolderPath)
        {
            string str = "-u -g --bake-infinity \"" + inputCLYTFilePath + "\" \"" + inputCLANFilePath + "\" \"" + outputFolderPath + "\"";
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            Util.Execute(this.convertPath, str, true);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.Write("{0} コンパイル時間(ms)", (object)outputFolderPath);
            Console.WriteLine(" . . . {0}", (object)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private void ConvertUpLayout()
        {
            this.ExecConvertLayout(this.layoutUName + ".clyt", this.layoutUName + ".clan", this.outputUFolderPath);
            this.ExecConvertLayout(this.layoutUPlayName + ".clyt", this.layoutUPlayName + ".clan", this.outputUPlayFolderPath);
        }

        private void ConvertDownLayout()
        {
            this.ExecConvertLayout(this.layoutDName + ".clyt", this.layoutDName + ".clan", this.outputDFolderPath);
            this.ExecConvertLayout(this.layoutDPlayName + ".clyt", this.layoutDPlayName + ".clan", this.outputDPlayFolderPath);
        }

        private void ConvertLayout(ref Theme theme)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            WaitWindow waitWindow = new WaitWindow();
            waitWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            waitWindow.Show();
            waitWindow.setPercentLabel("Wait：0/2");
            if (theme.IsFirstConvert || theme.IsDownChanged)
                this.ConvertDownLayout();
            waitWindow.setPercentLabel("Wait：1/2");
            if (theme.IsFirstConvert || theme.IsUpChanged)
                this.ConvertUpLayout();
            waitWindow.setPercentLabel("Wait：2/2");
            waitWindow.Close();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Please Wait(ms) = {0}", (object)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern uint SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, ref PreviewMaker.COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint flags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref PreviewMaker.RECT lpRect);

        public void OpenPreview()
        {
            this.hWnd = PreviewMaker.FindWindow("TMAKE", (string)null);
            if (!this.hWnd.Equals((object)IntPtr.Zero))
                return;
            try
            {
                new Process()
                {
                    StartInfo = {
                        FileName = this.lytviewerPath,
                        Arguments = (" --upper \"" + this.outputUFolderPath + "\" --lower \"" + this.outputDFolderPath + "\"")
                    }
                }.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                this.hWnd = PreviewMaker.FindWindow("TMAKE", (string)null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                int num = (int)MessageBox.Show((Window)this.rootWindow, ex.ToString(), Resources.Dialog_Err_Header);
            }
        }

        public void ActivePreview()
        {
            this.hWnd = PreviewMaker.FindWindow("TMAKE", (string)null);
            if (this.hWnd.Equals((object)IntPtr.Zero))
                return;
            PreviewMaker.SetForegroundWindow(this.hWnd);
        }

        public void ReloadPreviewWithDynamicLayout()
        {
            this.OpenPreview();
            PreviewMaker.COPYDATASTRUCT lParam = new PreviewMaker.COPYDATASTRUCT();
            PreviewMaker.LayoutProtocol layoutProtocol;
            layoutProtocol.Verb = "Open";
            layoutProtocol.Data = " -t upper " + this.outputUPlayFolderPath + " -t lower " + this.outputDPlayFolderPath;
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf((object)layoutProtocol));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr((object)layoutProtocol, ptr, false);
            lParam.lpData = ptr;
            lParam.cbData = 2112U;
            PreviewMaker.SendMessage(this.hWnd, 74, this.hWnd, ref lParam);
        }

        public void ReloadPreviewImage()
        {
            this.OpenPreview();
            PreviewMaker.COPYDATASTRUCT lParam = new PreviewMaker.COPYDATASTRUCT();
            PreviewMaker.LayoutProtocol layoutProtocol;
            layoutProtocol.Verb = "Open";
            layoutProtocol.Data = " -t upper " + this.outputUFolderPath + " -t lower " + this.outputDFolderPath;
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf((object)layoutProtocol));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr((object)layoutProtocol, ptr, false);
            lParam.lpData = ptr;
            lParam.cbData = 2112U;
            PreviewMaker.SendMessage(this.hWnd, 74, this.hWnd, ref lParam);
        }

        public void ChangePreviewParam(string paramData)
        {
            this.hWnd = PreviewMaker.FindWindow("TMAKE", (string)null);
            if (this.hWnd.Equals((object)IntPtr.Zero))
                this.ReloadPreviewImage();
            PreviewMaker.COPYDATASTRUCT lParam = new PreviewMaker.COPYDATASTRUCT();
            PreviewMaker.LayoutProtocol layoutProtocol;
            layoutProtocol.Verb = "Change";
            layoutProtocol.Data = paramData;
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf((object)layoutProtocol));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr((object)layoutProtocol, ptr, false);
            lParam.lpData = ptr;
            lParam.cbData = 2112U;
            PreviewMaker.SendMessage(this.hWnd, 74, this.hWnd, ref lParam);
            int lpdwProcessId;
            PreviewMaker.GetWindowThreadProcessId(this.hWnd, out lpdwProcessId);
            Interaction.AppActivate(lpdwProcessId);
        }

        public void ChangePreviewAnimationParam(int animParam)
        {
            this.ChangePreviewParam(" -anim " + (object)animParam);
        }

        public void ChangePreviewVisiblePaneParam(string paneName)
        {
            this.ChangePreviewParam(" -panevisible N_BaseCtr_00");
        }

        public void ChangePreviewPositionPaneParam(string paneName, int x, int y)
        {
            this.ChangePreviewParam(" -panetrans " + paneName + " " + (object)x + " " + (object)y);
        }

        public void MakePreview(ref Theme theme)
        {
            this.layoutManager.rootWindow = this.rootWindow;
            this.layoutManager.setThemeInfo(theme);
            if (this.layoutManager.changeLayout())
            {
                this.ConvertLayout(ref theme);
                this.ReloadPreviewImage();
                theme.IsFirstConvert = false;
                theme.setChangeFix();
            }
            else
            {
                int num = (int)MessageBox.Show((Window)this.rootWindow, Resources.Dialog_Err_Convert, Resources.Dialog_Err_Header);
            }
        }

        public void ClosePreview()
        {
            this.hWnd = PreviewMaker.FindWindow("TMAKE", (string)null);
            if (this.hWnd.Equals((object)IntPtr.Zero))
                return;
            PreviewMaker.RECT lpRect = new PreviewMaker.RECT();
            PreviewMaker.GetWindowRect(this.hWnd, ref lpRect);
            Settings.Default.lytviewerX = (double)lpRect.left;
            Settings.Default.lytviewerY = (double)lpRect.top;
            PreviewMaker.PostMessage(this.hWnd, 18, 0, 0);
        }

        public void CaptureReportImage(ref Theme theme, string captureFolderPath)
        {
            int num = theme.RecommendRowNum < eRecommendRowType.Row1 || theme.RecommendRowNum > eRecommendRowType.Row6 ? 11 : 5 + 7 * (int)(theme.RecommendRowNum - 1) + 6;
            this.ClosePreview();
            string str = "" + " --upper \"" + this.outputUFolderPath + "\"" + " --lower \"" + this.outputDFolderPath + "\"" + " --screenshot " + (object)num + " 0 \"" + captureFolderPath + "\"";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = this.lytviewerPath;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = str;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            this.hWnd = PreviewMaker.FindWindow("TMAKE", (string)null);
        }

        public void Capture(string captureFolderPath)
        {
            this.Capture(captureFolderPath, 0);
        }

        public void Capture(string captureFolderPath, int animationNum)
        {
            this.ClosePreview();
            string str1 = "";
            if (Settings.Default.CaptureTypeStr == "Both")
                str1 = str1 + " --upper \"" + this.outputUFolderPath + "\"" + " --lower \"" + this.outputDFolderPath + "\"";
            else if (Settings.Default.CaptureTypeStr == "Up")
                str1 = str1 + " --upper \"" + this.outputUFolderPath + "\"";
            else if (Settings.Default.CaptureTypeStr == "Down")
                str1 = str1 + " --lower \"" + this.outputDFolderPath + "\"";
            string str2 = str1 + " --screenshot " + (object)animationNum + " 0 \"" + captureFolderPath + "\"";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = this.lytviewerPath;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = str2;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            this.hWnd = PreviewMaker.FindWindow("TMAKE", (string)null);
        }

        private struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;
            public uint cbData;
            public IntPtr lpData;
        }

        public struct LayoutProtocol
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public string Verb;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
            public string Data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Classes are reference types, and the default value of a reference is `null`. So that `private PreviewMaker previewMaker;` field is `null` by default. You'll have to assign it, for example by creating a new `PreviewMaker` instance: `previewMaker = new PreviewMaker();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you create an instance of the `PreviewMaker` class, i.e. try to change this line in `RootWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
private PreviewMaker previewMaker;
```

...to this:

```
private PreviewMaker previewMaker = new PreviewMaker();
```

Comment: Oh...Thanks to you anyway

Comment: Re, I have the same error now with : `MessageBox.Show(this.rootWindow, Resources.Dialog_Err_Convert, Resources.Dialog_Err_Header);` rootWindow = `null`... Tried to change `public RootWindow rootWindow;` to `public RootWindow rootWindow = new RootWindow` 
But if I do this I get the following error: `{"An exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' has been thrown."}` What wrong?

Comment: Please you can help me?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. You are not supposed to ask addition questions in the comments field.

Comment: No, it is not. A StackOverflowException is not the same as a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Done. If you can help me, It will be great! Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

you declared previewMaker, but you don't initialize it before attempting to access it

in other words:

```
private PreviewMaker previewMaker;
```

will result in previewMaker being null.
that line DOES NOT create an object of the type PreviewMaker

Comment: Hi, 
So I have to put the "InitializeComponent ()" method just before?

Comment: you have to create an instance of that class and assign that instance to your class member "previewMaker" ... where you do that ... how you do that ... all of that depends on your application and can not be answered in general

Comment: I do not understand 
totally what you mean...Could you help me if I send you the full classes?If you do not mind

Comment: join me here, and i'll explain it to you ... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142286/fwin-and-the-nasty-null-pointers

Comment: well ... that's odd ... ok then ... first: in brief words... what is PreviewMaker? a component? a normal class?

Comment: PreviewMaker is a class made part of my project, also called "PreviewMaker.cs"

Comment: ok ... the member previewMaker ... in which class is it declared? ... and the class PreviewMaker ... does it have an available constructor?

Comment: Look at the top, I added the contents of the PreviewMaker.cs

Comment: ok ... i assume you declare the member in your window ... go find the constructor of your window class, and at its end, add `previewMaker = new PreviewMaker();`

Comment: Ok, like that :   `public void StartPreview_Theme()
        {
            this.setTheme();
            this.previewMaker.MakePreview(ref this.theme);
            previewMaker = new PreviewMaker();
        } ` Edit: Seem do not work

Comment: no ... look for a method that says `public NAME_OF_YOUR_CURRENT_CLASS_HERE()` while obviously substituting that name... and maybe you want to read a c# book ... just any of them...

Comment: Oh...In my `RootWindow` there is: 
        `private PreviewMaker previewMaker;` So I need the put that in `PreviewMaker.cs` right? If I put that, the name "PreviewMaker" is already taken

Comment: in your RootWindow there will likely somewhere be a constructor ... a method without return type, with the same name as your class ... if not, the window probably has a load event, or you can create one ... in the constructor add said line ...if there is no constructor ... look again ... if there really is no constructor, look for a load event ...

Comment: I know you have to replace the name you gave me, I found the `PreviewMaker public` but when I put `previewMaker = new PreviewMaker();`   Do I need to reference `RootWindow.xaml.cs`?

Comment: leave the PreviewMaker Class as it is ... open the file RootWindow.xaml.cs ... look for a line that says `public RootWindow()` ... or when in doubt ... post the file...

Comment: Not there's only : `private PreviewMaker previewMaker;` in my `RootWindow.xaml.cs` 
This problem is really annoying and I do not want to bother you more...

Comment: Ok but the `RootWindow.xaml`Has about 9000 lines

Comment: How can I send you that if there are "7427 lines" sorry

Comment: software design at its finest ... the file should start with some using directives ... followed by a namespace ... followed by a `public partial class RootWindow : Window` ... after that it probably has some lines of code we are not interested in but then eventually there will be a method that is calling `InitializeComponent()` ... right after that line ...

Comment: Finally @mm8 found, look down ... It was just because of that..Serious. Thank you to you too, you are superb